# How to call URL (API) in php in background, without getting 500 internal error

Tags: php, api, curl, web-applications

```
     $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiURL);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
     curl_exec($ch);
     curl_close($ch);
```

i used curl to call API in background. I basically want to call this URL in php, which help me to send an sms. So, all the patameters are done and made the URL. It works fine in localhost (with XAMPP). Everything works, user gets sms and fine. But when I upload this to VPS, it fails. I'm getting error 500, internal server error. As I discovered this happen due to timeout. Because, even when Im doing this on local host, it takes 2-3 seconds to run API and get back with a response.

Basically its not a sms sender. It's a kind of game which I made of javascript and I'm using AJAX to request to run function in php. So inside this function, i have another function to send sms. If I remove the code inside that function, so it works. Thats how I figured out that its getting time out, because it is taking some time to call this URL and get back.

my url set to $apiURL.

to fix this, i even set some rules. like bellow. but still same.

```
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiURL); // replace with your API URL
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $multiHandle = curl_multi_init();
    curl_multi_add_handle($multiHandle, $ch);
    $running = null;
    do {
        curl_multi_exec($multiHandle, $running);
    } while ($running);
    curl_multi_remove_handle($multiHandle, $ch);
    curl_multi_close($multiHandle);
    $response = curl_multi_getcontent($ch);
    echo $response;
    curl_close($ch);
    echo 'SMS Sent Successfully';
```

can someone help me to fix this issue. I just want to call this URL in background. without interupting the current process. Because I don't want to get the response in return. Just want to call this URL. Thats all.

```
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiURL); // replace with your API URL
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $multiHandle = curl_multi_init();
    curl_multi_add_handle($multiHandle, $ch);
    $running = null;
    do {
        curl_multi_exec($multiHandle, $running);
    } while ($running);
    curl_multi_remove_handle($multiHandle, $ch);
    curl_multi_close($multiHandle);
    $response = curl_multi_getcontent($ch);
    echo $response;
    curl_close($ch);
    echo 'SMS Sent Successfully';
```

Comment: It depends on the exact error, but it sounds like the connection to the remote host might be blocked by some firewall rule or similar. Try and ask your server admin about this.